# Multiple file extension validation

Tags: php, ajax

I have an html form where i have input file array. What im trying to achieve is get the file array in php file loop through it and check if a file extension is correct else add it to array and then show as json array in ajax. Can someone help me? here is the code for the form:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Multiple file upload handling</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form").submit(function(e){
        var file1 = $("#file1").val();
        var file2 = $("#file2").val();
        $("#results").text("");
        var results = $("#results");
        if(file1 == "" || file2 == ""){
            results.text("File 1 and File 2 are empty.");
        }else {
            var formarray = new FormData($("#form")[0]);
            $.ajax({
                url: "upload.php",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "JSON",
                enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: formarray,
                success:function(response){
                    if(response.success == false){
                        $(response.message).each(function(index, value){    
                            results.append("<li id="+ index + ">" + value + "</li>");
                        });
                    }else{
                        alert(response.message);
                    }
                }
            });
        }   
        e.preventDefault();
    });
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
      <form method="post" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">
        <input type="file" id="file1" name="file[]" style="margin-bottom:30px;"><br>
        <input type="file" id="file2" name="file[]" style="margin-bottom:30px;"><br>
      <input type="submit" id="upload" name="upload">
      </form>
      <div id="results"></div>
      </body>
      </html>
```

And below is the php code:

```
<?php
    $filenames = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $filesizes = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $file_tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $data = array();
    $errors = array();
    foreach($filenames as $key=>$value){
        $filesize = $_FILES["file"]["size"][$key];
        $filetype = $_FILES["file"]["type"][$key];
        $file_tmpname = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $valid_extensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "gif", "png");
        $ext = explode(".", $value);
        $extension = end($ext);
        if(!in_array($extension, $valid_extensions)){
            $errors[] = $value;
            $data["success"] = false;
            $data["message"] = $errors;
        } else {
            $data["success"] = true;
            $data["message"] = "success";
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmpname, "uploads/".$filename);
        }   
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue? What happens when you run this code? Any error messages?

Comment: The problem is that when i have a file with wrong extension it doesnt display it in the div with id results and im trying to display each file which is with wrong extension in the div.

Comment: I do see one issue though, you have two input fields `file1` and `file2`, while you're trying to fetch the data through `$_FILES['file']`. Have you checked your error logs? Checked the network tab what the actual response is in your ajax call? Do you have display_errors (in PHP) turned on?

Comment: **(#1)** Consider changing `$extension = end($ext);` into `$extension = strtolower(end($ext));` because all of your `$valid_extensions` are lowercase. **(#2)** What happens if I upload an extension-less file named `jpeg`? **(#3)** I have no idea how to solve the problem which you are having; I'm not in the mood to debug jQuery right now.

Comment: You can solve both #1 and #2 from my previous comment with `$extension = (count($ext) > 1 ? strtolower(end($ext)) : '');`. Also, put `$valid_extensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "gif", "png");` below `$errors = array();` because you do not need to re-declare the valid extensions for every file.

Comment: well i tried something just now and i tried uploading two files with incorrect file extensions and the results was that it adds both of the files to the div but what i want is have a file with correct extension and one with wrong extension and just show the file with wrong extension